# Run code if any of the "if...else if" was executed?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am want to run code if any of the bunch of `if + else if + else if...` was executed:

```
if(){
    ...
}else if(){
    ...
}else if(){
    ...
}
//run something if ANY of the above was executed
```

I could add the line that I want to execute on every `if` or `else if`, but that will be too much spam.

What I have done is the following:

```
temp=i;//store a copy
i=-1;//make the change

if(){
    ...
}else if(){
    ...
}else if(){
    ...
}else{
    i=temp//restore if none was executed
}
```

The above will apply the change regardless of anything, and undo this change with an `else`. This works fine, but I am really worried about the readability of this code

Are there other more readable alternatives that I am missing?

Comment: Could you try and add a more specific example?

Comment: Depending on what the conditions are I'd consider making them functions in a list, returning true or false. Loop over a list of them, and if any return true, stop the loop. After the loop check a flag that's been set inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always do

```
any=true;
if (...) {
} else if (...) {
} else if (...) {
} else {
  any = false;
  // or: return, if you are inside a function!
}
if (any) {
  // one of the ifs was executed.
}
```

If you use functions to wrap this, you can also just `return` in the final else. That probably is the cleanest version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need two variables. How about this?

```
var conditionMet = true;

if(){
    ...
}else if(){
    ...
}else if(){
    ...
}else{
    conditionMet = false;
}

if(conditionMet){
    ...
}
```

I think that for readability purpose the main thing here would be to find a really good name for the variable, depending on what it **actually** represents.